# replace line that contains search pattern entirely with another line

Tags: python, regex, replace

I would like to replace every line that starts with a certain expression (example: `<Output>`) with what I want the output path to be. I have found and got to work a python script that replaces one string with another, in every occurrence in a file - something like:

```
text = open( path ).read()
if output_pattern in text:
   open( path, 'w' ).write( text.replace( pattern, replace ) )
```

However I would like to replace the `text.replace( pattern, replace )` with something that replaces the entire line that contains `pattern` with `replace`. I have tried some things and failed miserably.

*Note: I can read but not quite write python...*

One of my failures did replace the pattern with the line. Actually, it replaced the entire file with only the replace pattern, as many times as it was needed... Yeah, not funny since I was doing a recursive search (and the previous attempt, to replace one string with another, worked perfectly, so I was brave and set my target directory as the root of what I want to work with)

There are other great examples that read line by line and write to an output file, and then copy the output file to the input file, but I got an error doing that.

I don't really want to use regex because the patterns that I might want to search for (and especially what I want to replace) (may) contain many special characters including backslashes, but these could be escaped if needed.

Comment: You should do this using 2 text files: one as *read* and the other *write*. Its best to set it up using `with`, `while True`, and `readline()`. You can create a test file of just the first ten lines, get it working, then run it on the real target. [Look here](http://effbot.org/zone/readline-performance.htm) for a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace lines with `replace` if they start with `pattern`:

```
text = open(path).read()
new_text = '\n'.join(replace if line.startswith(pattern) else line
                                for line in text.splitlines())
open(path, 'w').write(new_text)
```

Or optimized for memory usage, and using the `with` statement, which is a bit more idiomatic:

```
with open(input_path) as text, open(output_path, 'w') as new_text:
    new_text.write(''.join(replace if line.startswith(pattern) else line
                                for line in text))
```

You'll want to make sure `replace` has a newline character (`\n`) in it for the latter example to work as you'd expect.

Comment: True enough, I'll give an optimized and more idiomatic example.

Comment: @zeekay: doesn't the new version still read the entire file into memory and construct a ''-joined revised version before writing it?

Comment: Whoa...you can use two `open()` statements on one `with`?

Comment: Thank you ! The splitlines() was what I was missing from my experimenting ! The files I am using are not huge so it is perfect.
Not sure what the second version does with the ' '., and - will I not still need the text.splitlines() ?

Comment: having different input_path and output_path doesn't work - I need to fix files without having to manually do anything afterwords like copying one file over another, and from python, I got an error when I tried to replace the old file with the new file (it said that it can't write over old file because file already exists). Not sure why. That is why I am trying to just use one file.

Comment: Yeah you need to use a temporary file. Just do `os.rename(output_path, input_path)` afterwards.